# Black screen after hibernate on Macbook Air 2012

Tags: 18.04, hibernate, macbook-air

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and trying to make hibernation (sudo systemctl hibernate) working on my Macbook Air 2012. Actually it works so far, it wakes up, I can see grub but when it comes to the lock screen the screen flickers, also after login. Switchting with Alt Ctrl Fx doesn't help. But if I enter suspend using the power button and wake up again the flickering stops and everything works normal.

So I assume hibernation works but some driver is not initialized correctly. Can I configure something so the drivers are initilized after hibernation like after suspend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some months I found the trick. The i915 must be loaded early, so adding i915 to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules and updating the initramfs solves it.